# Rows to columns in oracle sql for multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have raw data as below in source table. i need this transformed as shown below.

| user_id | domain_id | id_value | id_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48085640 | ID1 | 21885688845 | 5 |
| 48085640 | ID1 | 20544518912 | 5 |
| 48085640 | ID2 | 176652329 | 5 |
| 48085640 | ID2 | 121702229 | 5 |
| 48085640 | ID3 | 111844976 | 5 |
| 48085640 | ID3 | 111347117 | 5 |
| 48085640 | ID4 | 1234567 | 5 |

And i am trying to achieve the output as below. There are two values for ID1, ID2, ID3. if i use pivot i must use an aggregate function like max() or min() i am losing one of the rows.also i need to fetch the ID1, ID2 and ID3 only and filter rest of the IDs. Please help me achieve this in oracle sql and also in impala if possible

| user_id | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | id_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48085640 | 218856888 | 1766523293 | 111844976 | 5 |
| 48085640 | 205445189 | 1217022297 | 111347117 | 5 |

Comment: Please search this site for `[oracle] pivot data`, which should give you enough information to use so that you can make an effort to solve the problem yourself. Once you've done that, if you run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you're having, include the sample data and expected output along with your efforts, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to give each row a number based on the order within each `user_id`/`domain_id` partition and then use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       id1,
       id2,
       id3,
       id_status
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, domain_id ORDER BY ROWNUM)
           AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(id_value)
  FOR domain_id IN ('ID1' AS id1, 'ID2' AS id2, 'ID3' AS id3)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (user_id, domain_id, id_value, id_status) AS
SELECT 48085640, 'ID1', 21885688845, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 48085640, 'ID1', 20544518912, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 48085640, 'ID2',   176652329, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 48085640, 'ID2',   121702229, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 48085640, 'ID3',   111844976, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 48085640, 'ID3',   111347117, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 48085640, 'ID4',     1234567, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | USER_ID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID_STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 48085640 | 21885688845 | 176652329 | 111844976 | 5 |
> | 48085640 | 20544518912 | 121702229 | 111347117 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EnHmogXm)*

Answer (score 0):

You can always manualy pivot this data and then join it to itsefl for each IDs.

Let's try:

```
 CREATE TABLE ABC_123 (
user_id NUMBER,     domain_id varchar2(3),  id_value NUMBER,    id_status number );

begin
INSERT INTO ABC_123 values (48085640, 'ID1', 21885688845, 5);
INSERT INTO ABC_123 values (48085640, 'ID1', 20544518912 ,5);
INSERT INTO ABC_123 values (48085640, 'ID2', 176652329 ,5);
INSERT INTO ABC_123 values (48085640, 'ID2', 121702229 ,5);
INSERT INTO ABC_123 values (48085640, 'ID3', 111844976 ,5);
INSERT INTO ABC_123 values (48085640, 'ID3', 111347117 ,5);
INSERT INTO ABC_123 values (48085640, 'ID4', 1234567 ,5);
END;

COMMIT;

WITH pivot_data as
( SELECT user_id
, CASE WHEN domain_id = 'ID1' THEN id_value ELSE NULL END AS ID1 
, CASE WHEN domain_id = 'ID2' THEN id_value ELSE NULL END AS ID2
, CASE WHEN domain_id = 'ID3' THEN id_value ELSE NULL END AS ID3
, row_number() over(PARTITION BY  domain_id ORDER BY 1 /* order by is not important, but is mandatory*/ ) AS rownum_for_domain_id
, id_status
FROM ABC_123 )
SELECT d1.user_id, d1.ID1, d2.ID2, d3.ID3, d1.id_status
FROM pivot_data d1  /* inner for domain_id = 'ID1' - it determines number of rows */
LEFT JOIN pivot_data d2
 ON d1.user_id = d2.user_id
 AND d2.ID2 IS NOT NULL 
 AND d2.rownum_for_domain_id = d1.rownum_for_domain_id
LEFT JOIN pivot_data d3
 ON d1.user_id = d3.user_id
 AND d3.ID3 IS NOT NULL 
 AND d3.rownum_for_domain_id = d1.rownum_for_domain_id
WHERE d1.ID1 IS NOT null ;
```

| USER_ID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48085640 | 21885688845 | 176652329 | 111844976 | 5 |
| 48085640 | 20544518912 | 121702229 | 111347117 | 5 |